# Snowflake interpreting timestamp wrong?

Tags: json, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm loading a bunch of semi-structured data (JSON) into my database through Snowflake. The timestamp values in the entries are javascript timestamps that look like this:
`"time": 1621447619899`

Snowflake automatically converts this into a timestamp variable that looks like this:
`53351-08-15 22:04:10.000`.

All good so far. However, I think that the new timestamp is wrong. The actual datetime should by May 19, 2021 around 12pm MDT. Am I reading it wrong? Is it dependent on the timezone that my Snowflake instance is in?

Comment: If the value `1621447619899` is inside a JSON attribute, there is no "automatic" conversion of that data in Snowflake at all.  It will always treat that value as a JSON object until you cast it to something else.  If you could provide the code where you are parsing out the JSON attribute to a timestamp value, that would be helpful.

Comment: Hey Mike, see my response to Felipe below. Do you know why `value:time::timestamp` isn't correctly parsing the JSON? All my other values parse correctly out of that JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing the following options manually in SQL:

```
with x as (
    SELECT parse_json('{time:1621447619899}') as var
    )
SELECT var:time,
       var:time::number,
       var:time::varchar::timestamp,
       1621447619899::timestamp,
       '1621447619899'::timestamp,
       var:time::timestamp
FROM x;
```

It appears that what you want to do is execute the following:

```
var:time::varchar::timestamp
```

Reviewing the documentation it does look like the to_timestamp is looking for the number as a string, so you need to cast to varchar first, and then cast to timestamp, otherwise you get what you are getting.

Comment: Thanks, @MattNorton.  Please be sure to mark the solution as your chosen solution and uptick the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The ::timestamp handles strings and numeric inputs differently. I.e. a string is added to 1970-01-01 as milliseconds (correct) whereas the numeric value is added in seconds which returns a date way in the future "53351-08-18 20:38:19.000".

```
SELECT TO_VARCHAR(1621447619899::timestamp) AS numeric_input
      ,'1621447619899'::timestamp AS string_input
```

numeric_input = 53351-08-18 20:38:19.000

string_input = 2021-05-19 18:06:59.899

Solutions are to convert to a string or divide by 1000:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(time::string)
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(time/1000)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The question says that Snowflake transforms it to "53351-08-15 22:04:10.000" looks right, but it doesn't look right to me.

When I try the input number in Snowflake I get this:

```sql
select '1621447619899'::timestamp;

-- 2021-05-19T18:06:59.899Z
```

That makes a lot more sense.

You'll need to provide more code or context for further debugging - but if you tell Snowflake to transform that number to a timestamp, you'll get the correct timestamp out.

See the rules that Snowflake uses here:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html#usage-notes

Comment: Thanks Felipe! I guess I just meant that it looks right in format - but the values are obviously off.  Here is the code that I'm using to transform the value into a timestamp:

`create or replace table AudienceEntries as
select
   value:time::timestamp       as Time

from table
, lateral flatten (input => v:entries);`

Comment: I just tried importing the value:time both as a string and an int, then converting the column to timestamp. Both options failed with an error "cannot change column TIME from type VARCHAR(16777216) to TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)" or "cannot change column TIME from type NUMBER(38,0) to TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)"

Comment: Can you share the json object, to let me reproduce?